# How to use Visual Studio 2012 to create SQL Server Reporting Service 2012 projects?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I wanted to update my SSRS reports to use 2012, so i installed SQL Server 2012 and checked off data tools and reporting services.  It installed successfully and under my Microsoft SQL Server 2012 programs directory i see "SQL Server Data Tools", however when i open SQL Server Data Tools, it opens a Visual Studio **2010** project. And when i start a

And when I start a new Reporting Service project, my rdl files have 2008 schema in the xml. I am very confused. So how can i use VS2012 and make 2012 reports?

Comment: To be honest, I never got it to work correctly with IIS/SQL 2012/SSRS/VS 12 all on the same server. For whatever reason, Visual Studio installed something on the IIS server that made the entire IIS server unusable. I was able to undo it all and just stick with the SSRS interface within SQL.

Comment: That seems to be the consensus. I'm guessing this is why Microsoft moved on to SQL 2014 so quickly. Get out while you can!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no SSDT(Sql server data tools) available for Visual Studio 2012. We have to use Visual studio 2010(Only the Shell with reporting services template is sufficient) to work with Reporting Service Projects and Sql Server 2012.

I have just realized that now SSDT for VS 2012 is available. It will install Business Intelligence templates in VS 2012.

[VS2012 BI templates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrsteamblog/archive/2013/03/06/sql-server-data-tools-business-intelligence-for-visual-studio-2012-released-online.aspx)